# Import OVF 2.0 Vector field files

Tags: import, vector, binary

I'm using a simulation software ([mumax3](https://mumax.github.io/)) which outputs [OVF_2.0](https://math.nist.gov/oommf/doc/userguide12b3/userguide/OVF_2.0_format.html) files. It can either export binary or text files. The binary files are usually much smaller than the text files. I would like to use the binary option, and I am looking for a way to import them in Mathematica.

Comment: Yeah!!! mumax3 what’s up!! Hah! Have you seen [`ovf2mathematica.go`](https://gist.github.com/salviati/da3edc4cd643749cbcf0a8c85c8b67b4)?

Comment: Walter, have you seen the new functionality to output a numpy array? I’ll try to write something for maybe like a dataset here or something, but I wonder if you can instead use the external evaluate functionality to import it as a numpy array?

Comment: @CATrevillian that ovf2mathematica.go is great! I am not sure what output you are talking about? I did not see a new, documented, feature in mumax that allows writing HDF5 files or anything else regarding numpy arrays in mumax. I vaguely remember someone talking about this though....

Comment: I’m not sure about hdf5, but mentioned in the new release notes is that mumax3-convert can take the ovf files and convert them to numpy arrays, among other useful formats.

Comment: That is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, but you have to figure out the size of the header and footer beforehand.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

(*the header in this file is 479 bytes*)
import = Import["m000000.ovf", {"Binary", "Real32"},"HeaderBytes" -> (479)];

(*the footer in this file is 40 bytes. With 4 bytes (32bit) per number, this is the last 10 entries in "import"*)

data = import[[2 ;; -10]];
```

The lengths of header and footer can be found by importing the data in a different way:

```
In[1]:= 
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
import = Import["m000000.ovf", "Binary"];

In[3]:= 
(*Look at header*)
FromCharacterCode[import[[1 ;; 10]]]
FromCharacterCode[import[[1 ;; 20]]]
(*Look at footer*)
FromCharacterCode[import[[-10 ;; -1]]]
FromCharacterCode[import[[-20 ;; -1]]]

Out[3]= 
"# OOMMF OV"

Out[4]= 
"# OOMMF OVF 2.0
# Se"

Out[5]= 
": Segment
"

Out[6]= 
"ry 4
# End: Segment
"
```

By varying the part of the imported file (1;;10, 1;;20, ... 1;;479) that is converted to character code, you can find the lengths manually. Surely there is a better way to do this. Preferably one that does not require importing the file twice.

Comment: Can you, possibly, share the link to your example file in an edit to your self-answer?